# Pro guard error building release apk

Tags: android, android-build

I'm getting the following error trying to build a release apk

```
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:proguardRelease
Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplBase: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplGingerbread: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatGingerbread: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED
```

In the build.gradle I have this:

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
}

And still get the same error if I change it to `"com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0"`

When the error message says this: "You probably need to update the library versions." What library is it referring to and how do I update it?

The documentation referenced in the error says:
 `"If you're developing for Android and ProGuard complains that it can't find a method that is only available in a recent version of the Android run-time, you should change the build target in your project.properties file or build.gradle file to that recent version. You can still specify a different minSdkVersion and a different targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml file."`

Here is my build.gradle, which is as most recent as there is as its API 23.
So how can I fix the problem?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cequint.ecid"
        minSdkVersion 23
        compileSdkVersion 23
    }
```

Comment: did you try updating to `com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0` ?

Comment: Its the same error message after updating to com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0

Comment: I added this to pro guard.cfg and it worked: -dontwarn android.support.v4.**

Comment: Glad you figured it out, i suggest answering your own question then accepting then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added this to pro guard.cfg and it worked:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

Comment: Are you actually utilizing the NotificationCompat and its builder? I added this file, but am now getting runtime exceptions instead

Comment: Yes I'm using NotificationCompat. Do you mean you started using NotificationCompat and then started getting exceptions when you do so? If so you may be missing a dependency in your gradle file

Comment: Turned out it was an unrelated change that caused it. Never mind me.